# Join or storing directly

Tags: sql, database, database-design, rdbms

I have a table A which contains entries I am regularly processing and storing the result in table B. Now I want to determine for each entry in A its latest processing date in B.

My current implementation is joining both tables and retrieving the latest date. However an alternative, maybe less flexible, approach would be to simply store the date in table A directly.

I can think of pros and cons for both cases (performance, scalability, ....), but didnt have such a case yet and would like to see whether someone here on stackoverflow had a similar situation and has a recommendation for either one for a specific reason.

Below a quick schema design.

```
Table A
id, some-data, [possibly-here-last-process-date]

Table B
fk-for-A, data, date
```

Thanks

Comment: can you include the schema for both tables as well as some sample related data in both for illustration?  a picture speaks 1000 words

Comment: @user1709867: When people here ask for a schema, they usually want the SQL `CREATE TABLE` statements. Shorthand like 'some-data' and 'data' can cover a multitude of sins.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a table whose each row is a parameter and another table that logs each parameter value historically in a time series.  If that is correct, I currently have the same situation in one of the products I am building.  My parameter table hosts a listing of measures (29K recs) and the historical parameter value table has the value for that parameter every 1 hr -  so that table currently has 4M rows.  At any given point in time there will be a lot more requests FOR THE LATEST VALUE than for the history so I DO HAVE THE LATEST VALUE STORED IN THE PARAMETER TABLE in addition to it being in the last record in the parameter value table.  While this may look like duplication of data, from the performance standpoint it makes perfect sense because

1. To get a listing of all parameters and their CURRENT VALUE, I do not have to make a join and more importantly
2. I do not have to get the latest value for each parameter from such a huge table

So yes, I would in your case most definitely store the latest value in the parent table and update it every time new data comes in.  It will be a little slower for writing new data but a hell of a lot faster for reads.

Comment: Thanks foampile. I'd have more or less the same comment as to Vikdor's response. The reason why I'd be still tempted to stick to the current implementation due to its seemingly better reliability (if I remove a row for whatever reason I wont need to update A as the data will be calculated on the fly) and data normalisation (you mentioned it already). Did your decision come from gut feeling or did you find any further information on it?

Comment: it is not a "gut feeling", it is clearly a matter of better performance overall, i.e. a sensible tradeoff

Comment: This is a terribnle idea, it requires a trigger to maintain the data properly.

Comment: I see your point, even though with proper indexes performance _should_ not be the main issue. Did you have a case where you used the first approach and ran into performance issues?

Comment: @HLGEM not necessarily, when you insert a new record into B you update A

Comment: for each parameter, i have 100s of rows in the history table and i only need the latest one.  so i would have to 1.  find what the latest record is using a GROUP BY on a table with millions of rows and then 2. join to that recordset -- that would be just insane.  my solution performs lightening fast and the history table is used only if the user wants to see a chart of historical listing, which is very, very rare.

Comment: As far as insanity is concerned I sorta agree, however often things appear to be insane in IT ;). Considering there are proper indexes I wonder whether it would be still such a performance hit using joins. Of course, using only A would be always faster as there are no joins involved but I'd be curious whether the difference is really that great (again, considering full utilisation of indexes).

Comment: the performance benefits are clear in eliminating the huge table for querying.  the tradeoff for updating the master table is minimal.  indexes will get you only so far but never as far as not needing to query the history table at all

Comment: @foampile: You said, "I would have to 1. find what the latest record is using a GROUP BY...". You don't need a GROUP BY to select the latest row for a given primary key from a table.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, it sounds like Table B is your historical (or archive) table and it's populated by batch.

I would leave Table A alone and just introduce an index on id and date. If the historical table is big, introduce an auto-increment PK for table B and have a separate table that maps the B-Pkid to A-pkid.

I'm not a fan of UPDATE on a warehouse table, that's why I didn't recommend a CURRENT_IND, but that's an alternative.

Comment: You are correct. This is sort of my current implementation but (even though I am with you about the update on A) I share the concerns of Vikdor and foampile about performance (even with proper indexes). Why would you recommend an additional table to map A and B? Having only an n-to-1 relationship I would assume having the right mapping in B should be sufficient, shouldnt it?

Comment: I assumed that A is your transactional table and can never be taken offline and table B may be moved to a different server in the future for performance reason. If performance is the goal, table C is essentially your pseudo-index filtered only to the max row. Therefore, you don't have to perform the max subquery everytime you need data from table B.

Comment: Reading back at my answer, I can understand why it's a head scratcher. I didn't elaborate that table C only contain the mapping of the max row. By the way, you can create a view so that the user doesn't have to code table B to table C join.

Comment: Basically both tables are never supposed to be offline. Lets see whether I understood you right, C would be identical to B with the exception that it has to be a view (and not a table) and always only contains the last element of B for a given entry in A?!

Comment: C will just contain the A pkid and B pkid of the max row. The view suggestion is to encapsulate the join of B and C.

Comment: I still dont understand why I would need C. I'd would need it if it were N-to-N, but thats not the case here. So what could it do what I couldnt achieve with a simple A-B join? Unless you suggest I update C when I insert a new record into B.

Comment: To be able to join A -> B, you need to get the max row (an extra subselect which will cost you) everytime you run a query. Yes, I am implying updating C when you create a record in B. However, I would rather rebuild C than update, but you have to try it out to see which one is faster.

Comment: I now see what you mean, but in that case I would lose the advantage of having everything dynamic as I would still need to update C (which would be A in the other case). Also a left join with MAX(B.date) would do the trick, no need to a manual subselect here.

Comment: Gotcha. Your requirement is actually simpler that I thought. You just want a last update timestamp and nothing else.

Comment: Kind of. Basically B contains all the data collected for A and so I want to get, among other data, also the last processing data from B. My first intuition was to join B to A but then I got the same concerns foampile expressed and considered to simply store this data in A (slight duplication) and since then I am undecided between both.

Comment: Gotcha. Your requirement is actually simpler that I thought. You just want a last update timestamp and nothing else. I agree with adding the date in table A. Sorry to drag you through the data warehousing method. At least, I shared my idea on how to implement a point in time table with efficient latest values option. Just make sure that you "save" the date in a variable first before updating A and B.

Comment: By the way, I will keep your MAX(date) right now until it gives you trouble. We often over-architect things un-necessarily, but having a contingency plan is never bad.

Comment: I know, especially I have the tendency to get lost in details and over-architecturing could have been invented by me :D. But what do you mean by you will keep it? Dont quite get that sentence.

Comment: Ignore the idea of worrying about the performance issue, for now. Just keep using the MAX(date) until there are observable performance hit. Depending on how your "key" is generated, I doubt that you'll encounter the hypothetical performance hit.

Comment: Okay, now I got you. You meant you would keep the JOIN, but that contradicts your statement to add the date to A. Why the change of mind?

Comment: Because I tend to skim through text and not read it completely. You mentioned "but didnt have such a case yet".

Comment: I wasnt referring to performance issues but to this task where I am between keep the date redundant in two tables or use a join.

Comment: I will continue to use the JOIN (which is working out for you) until I start encountering a performance hit. My motto is that things are not necessary until they are necessary.

Comment: So your suggestion to store the date in A was based on your belief that I encountered performance issues, right?

Comment: Yes. If you encounter performance problems, then add the date to A.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly typical question; there are lots of reasonable answers, but there is only one correct approach (in my opinion).

You're basically asking "should I denormalize my schema?". I believe that you should denormalize your schema only if you really, really have to. The way you know you have to is because you can prove that - under current or anticipated circumstances - you have a performance problem with real-life queries.

On modern hardware, with a well-tuned database, finding the latest record in table B by doing a join is almost certainly not going to have a noticable performance impact unless you have HUGE amounts of data.

So, my recommendation: create a test system, populate the two tables with twice as much data as the system will ever need, and run the queries you have on the production environment. Check the query plans, and see if you can optimize the queries and/or indexing. If you really can't make it work, de-normalize the table.

Whilst this may seem like a lot of work, denormalization is a big deal - in my experience, on a moderately complex system, denormalized data schemas are at the heart of a lot of stupid bugs. It makes introducing new developers harder, it means additional complexity at the application level, and the extra code means more maintenance. In your case, if the code which updates table A fails, you will be producing bogus results without ever knowing about it; an undetected bug could affect lots of data.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar situation in our project tracking system where the latest state of the project is stored in the `projects` table `(Cols: project_id, description etc.,)` and the history of the project is stored in the `project_history` table `(Cols: project_id, update_id, description etc.,)`. Whenever there is a new update to the project, we need find out the latest update number and add 1 to it to get the sequence number for the next update. We could have done this by grouping the `project_history` table on the `project_id` column and get the `MAX(update_id)`, but the cost would be high considering the number of the project updates (in a couple of hundreds of thousands) and the frequency of update. So, we decided to store the value in the `projects` table itself in `max_update_id` column and keep updating it whenever there is a new update to a given project. HTH.

Comment: Thanks Vikdor, this is kinda my issue. I'd be only still tempted to stick to the current implementation due to its seemingly better reliability (if I remove a row for whatever reason I wont need to update A as the data will be calculated on the fly) and data normalisation. Did your decision come from gut feeling or did you find any further information on it?

Comment: We started off without the `max_update_id` and later on added this as an optimization step to avoid an aggregate query on an ever-growing table.

Comment: Did you run into performance issues (assuming you had proper indexation)?

Comment: We didn't run into obvious performance issues when we made the change. The change came out as a recommendation in a review by a senior developer who chose to have an additional column in the primary table to prevent running aggregating queries on the history table.

Comment: I see. It sounds reasonable. Thank you Vikdor

Comment: Thanks Vikdor. Sorry for not choosing your answer as correct one (even though it is kinda identical to foampile's) but as his reputation value is lower I thought it would be fair to give him precendence here.